# Add required attribute when you add form inputs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where dynamically, the user can add/delete form inputs. The problem is that in `form-group` which is hidden, I can't add the attribute `required` because in submit event, the submit won't happen.

How can I add the attribute `required` every time i press + button and delete it when I press - button?

I tried this: `$('#barcode').prop('required',true);` but isn't right because if I press 2 times the  + button, I will have 2 inputs with the same id...

```js
var counter = 0;

$('#form1')
  // Add button click handler
  .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
    counter++;
    var $template = $('#addLine'),
      $clone = $template
      .clone()
      .removeClass('hide')
      .removeAttr('id')
      .attr('data-index', counter)
      .insertBefore($template);

    // Update the name attributes
    $clone
      .find('[name="barcode"]').attr('name', 'barcode-' + counter).end()
      .find('[name="productsInBox"]').attr('name', 'productsInBox-' + counter).end()
      .find('[name="packer"]').attr('name', 'packer-' + counter).end()
      .find('[name="count"]').attr('name', 'count-' + counter).end();

    $('#barcode').prop('required', true);
  })

// Remove button click handler
.on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
    index = $row.attr('data-index');
  counter--;
  // Remove element containing the fields
  $('#barcode').prop('required', false);
  $row.remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="actions?do=barcodePaleta_submit" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">box:</label>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" pattern=".{23,23}" class="form-control" name="barcode" required/>
          </div>

          <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">num:</label>
          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3">
            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="productsInBox" required/>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="addLine" class="form-group hide">
          <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">box:</label>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            <input id="barcode" type="text" pattern=".{23,23}" class="form-control" name="barcode" />
          </div>

          <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">num:</label>
          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3">
            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="productsInBox" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group myTop">
          <div class="col-lg-10 ">
            <button type="submit" name="formAction" value="next" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I miss understood question.try this for + button

```
if($('#barcode').attr('required') != true){
       $('#barcode').attr('required',true);
    }
```

this for - button

```
if($('#barcode').attr('required')){
           $('#barcode').removeAttr('required');
        }
```

Comment: your answer is wrong because if the user press the + button 5 times you will have the  `id="barcode"` 5 times which is wrong.

Comment: you right i miss understood question now i edit my answer